# Max() inner join

Tags: axapta, x++

I have two tables.

DOCUMENT and REVISION

I want to make a list of all documents and show the latest revision.
It works fine to find MAX(revision.autonumber) but as soon as I do inner join I no longer get the correct result. I then get not only the MAX(revision.autonumber) but also earlier revisions.

Thanks for your help

I have tried the query below (and many other attempts)

```
select
document.ItemId,
document.Name,
Max(revision.autonumber) 

from document

inner join 
revision on document.ItemId = revision.itemid 


group by
document.ItemId,
document.Name,
revision.doctitle
```

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Thank for your reply - Microsoft Dynamics AX

Comment: What version of AX? Are these custom tables in AX or base ones? If they're base, what are their actual names?

Comment: Is this even a X++ query? `inner` is [not a X++ keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-syntax). If you need a SQL query solution, then have a look a [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ed93bb6d175a3011fb67c154e92fe98). Do not forget to add the `Partition` and `DataAreaId` fields to enable index usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view on `revision` containing only `Max(revision.autonumber)`

Then do the join between the view and the `document`table.

This will work in Axapta 3.0 and up.